# the way/as/how/like he did it. What's the difference?

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

> I'll do it **the way** he did it.
>
> I'll do it **as** he did it.
>
> I'll do it **how** he did it.
>
> I'll do it **like** he did it.

Are all of them grammatically correct?
Do all of them mean the same?

Comment: Sentence 3 seems strange.

Comment: @CopperKettle, would you go as far as to say it's grammatically incorrect?

Comment: No, I'll *[take the fifth](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take_the_fifth)* on that. (0:

Comment: I've just recalled it: the possible reason we can't use **how** is because it's part of an *[interrogative content clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_clause)*

Comment: The "How" sentence is a colloquialism, commonly heard in southern and southeastern states. How in the sense of: "the way in which."

Answer (score 5):

### Short Answer:

Aside from the third one (with *how*), all your sentences are correct and mean the same thing. The fourth (with *like*) is informal, and not normally used in serious speech or writing.

### Long Answer:

All your sentences consist of two clauses, a main clause (*I'll do it*), plus a subordinate clause (*he did it*), and your question is about the terms that can join these two clauses, i.e., about *subordinate conjunctions*.

Let's take them one by one. The third is the only tricky one, so I'll save it for last.

---

This is the first definition OED provides for [**way**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/way):

> a method, style or manner of doing something:
>   - **way to do something** *That's not the right way to hold a pair of scissors.*
>   - *(informal, disapproving) **That's no way** to speak to your mother!*
>   - **way of doing something** *I'm not happy with this way of working.*
>   - **way (that…)** *It's not what you say, it's the way that you say it.*
>   - *I hate the way she always criticizes me.*
>   ...

As you can see, your first sentence perfectly fits this definition and its examples:

> I'll do it the way (that) he did it.

This is a valid usage of *way*, among other constructions that you can use after this word. I don't think anybody's called *way* a conjunction, but in your sentence it acts like one, because of the hidden *that* which I hinted at in the parentheses.

---

[**As**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/as), simply, *is* a conjunction,

> used to indicate by comparison the way that something happens or is done:
>   *Dress as you would if you were having guests.*
>   *They can do as they wish.*

Look at its definition: *"...**the way that** something happens ..."* . It suggests that there should be no difference between choosing *as* or *the way* in your sentence.

---

[**Like**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/like) can be used as a conjunction too, [but some people consider this use to be incorrect](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/like_5). We don't have to go that far, because it's so widespread in the informal register that you can't say it's wrong. It's just informal:

> (*informal*)
>   In the same way that; **as**:
>   *People who change countries like they change clothes*.

Notice the **as** in the definition. So up to now we have three equivalent terms to use as a conjunction. (Watch out for the informality of *like* (instead of *as*) though!)

---

***How*** is the tricky one here. It's certainly used as a conjunction sometimes, as in

> *You should remember how they fought.*

But is it used for comparison? as in

> **I'll do it how he did it.*

Well, Michael Swan in his book *Practical English Usage* says no, we can't use *how* this way:

> **comparisons: *how* not used**
>   In comparisons we use *as* or *like* or *the way*, not *how*.
>   *Hold it in both hands as/like/the way Mummy does.* (NOT ... *<s>how Mummy does</s>*)

---

So, aside from the third one (with *how*), all your sentences are OK, without any significant difference in meaning.
You can take a look at this [Ngram diagram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do+it+the+way+he%2Cdo+it+as+he%2Cdo+it+like+he%2Cdo+it+how+he&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdo%20it%20the%20way%20he%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdo%20it%20as%20he%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdo%20it%20like%20he%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdo%20it%20how%20he%3B%2Cc0) too:

[image]

See the hits for "do it how he". Almost none is relevant.