# difference between "as" and "how" - wrong example in the Cambridge Dictionary?

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions

I learned in this thread "[the way/as/how/like he did it. What's the difference?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/77848/the-way-as-how-like-he-did-it-whats-the-difference)" that we can't use "how" as a conjunction to make a comparison. We have to use "as" instead. For example the sentence:

- I'll do it as he did it.

Here https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/how however, I found the sentence:

- I don't care about fashion, I dress how I please.

Isn't "how" used as a conjunction to make a comparison in this sentence? Who is wrong/ right?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I dress how I please" sounds colloquial to me, but not incorrect (in American English). CGEL p. 1077 gives "I don't like how it looks" as dialectal.

Comment: This comment matches my intuitions: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/77848/the-way-as-how-like-he-did-it-whats-the-difference#comment150179_77848

Answer (score 0):

It might be that **how** is being used as a short version of **however**, because:

> I dress however I want [please].

would be very common.